# Loop operator "For" to fill an array in VHDL

Tags: for-loop, vhdl

I want to understand and improve an VHDL code I got.

In the VHDL implementation there is the following part:

```
m1(000) <=          MetricA(000)    + BrMet(3);
m1(001) <=          MetricA(001)    + BrMet(1);
m1(002) <=          MetricA(002)    + BrMet(0);
m1(003) <=          MetricA(003)    + BrMet(2);
m1(004) <=          MetricA(004)    + BrMet(0);
m1(005) <=          MetricA(005)    + BrMet(2);
m1(006) <=          MetricA(006)    + BrMet(3);
m1(007) <=          MetricA(007)    + BrMet(1);
m1(008) <=          MetricA(008)    + BrMet(2);
m1(009) <=          MetricA(009)    + BrMet(0);
m1(010) <=          MetricA(010)    + BrMet(1);
m1(011) <=          MetricA(011)    + BrMet(3);
m1(012) <=          MetricA(012)    + BrMet(1);
m1(013) <=          MetricA(013)    + BrMet(3);
m1(014) <=          MetricA(014)    + BrMet(2);
m1(015) <=          MetricA(015)    + BrMet(0);
```

where

```
type   BRANCH_METRIC is array (3 downto 0) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
signal BrMet:   RANCH_METRIC        :=  (OTHERS =>(OTHERS => '0'));


type   PATH_METRIC is array (15downto 0) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
signal MetricA: PATH_METRIC     :=  (OTHERS =>(OTHERS => '0'));
```

**My questions:**

**1.**  `m1(001), ....   m1(015)` ,  `MetricA(001), ....   MetricA(015)`  mean a value in a position:
`m1(001)` means a value on the first cell,  `m1(015)` is on the 15th cell.
Can `BrMet(0)` mean something else?

**2.** My task is to rewrite code above using `for`-loop.
I can write :

```
for i in 1 to 15 loop 
m1(i) <=          MetricA(i)    + BrMet(?);
```

How can I add  `BrMet`  in this loop?

I was thinking to create a table as:

```
Tab = {3,1,0,2,0,2...}
```

{3,1,0,2,0,2...} expresses BrMet(3), BrMet(1), BrMet(0) and so on

and the I would write the loop as

```
for i in 1 to 15 loop 
m1(i) <=          MetricA(i)    + Tab(i);
```

But unfortunately I didnt find any information how to create a table in VHDL. There is LUT table , bit It doesnt pass for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"*`m1(001)` means a value on the first cell, `m1(015)` is on the 15th cell*"

If by "*first cell*" you mean the cell with the smallest index then no, `m1(1)` is not the "first" cell, it is the "second" (and `m1(15)` is the "sixteenth") because you declared your array type with 0 as the "first" index, not 1. Note that, according these array definitions your loops are probably wrong: they should start at index 0, not 1.

"*Can `BrMet(0)` mean something else?*"

Else than what? `BrMet(0)` is the cell of array `BrMet` with the smallest index.

"*How can I add `BrMet` in this loop?*"

You apparently know how to declare array types and use them. This is no different. Just declare an array type and a constant of this type:

```vhdl
type BrMetIdx_t is array(0 to 15) of integer;
constant BrMetIdx: BrMetIdx_t := (3, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 0);
...
for i in 0 to 15 loop 
  m1(i) <= MetricA(i) + BrMet(BrMetIdx(i));
end loop;
...
```

Note: it would probably be safer to restrict the type of elements of `BrMetIdx_t` arrays to integers in the 0 to 3 range:

```vhdl
type BrMetIdx_t is array(0 to 15) of integer range 0 to 3;
```

This way, if there is a typo with, e.g., value 4, in your constant declaration you will get a clear error message from the compiler.

Note: you don't have to declare your array types with a "*downto*" index range. This is a common practice for vectors of bits because indexing them from right to left is also common but for your `m1`, `MetricA` and `BrMet` arrays you could probably as well index them in a more "*natural*" way:

```vhdl
type   BRANCH_METRIC is array (0 to 3) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
type   PATH_METRIC is array (0 to 15) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
```

This would probably help the global understanding.

Note: I doubt that you will ever use multiple drive for the path and branch metrics of your (Viterbi?) decoder. It would thus be safer to use an unresolved type like `std_ulogic_vector` instead of `std_logic_vector`. This way, if by accident you create a multiple drive situation, you will get a clear error message from the compiler instead of spending hours trying to understand why you see all these `X` values during simulation.